# Redirecting entire root and its content to new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect a folder and all its articles to a new domain:

olddomain.net/news/ to new-domain.com/news/

This is what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?olddomain\.net$ [NC] 

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www\.new\-domain\.com/news/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but this only redirects the folder root but not the individual articles. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Keep above rule inside `/news/` folder of old domain

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?olddomain\.net$ [NC] 

RewriteRule ^news http://www\.new\-domain\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```